# Cant get a RewriteRule work

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am working on a small dynamic website with php, and try to create a rewrite so the urls look more nice. (I use XAMPP)

The rootfolder is current "localhost/students".
First of all does the `.htaccess`need to be inside of that folder or of the localhost folder?

Secondary, i want all my requests go to the `index.php` but do not show "index.php". Moreover i'd love to rewrite something like `students\index.php?site=question&question=1` to `students\question\1`

So i tried to get started like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /students
RewriteRule ^/question/([0-9]+)$   index.php?site=question&question=$1
```

But this does actually nothing. How do i do it right? Is there a better solution to rewrite the urls?

Last but not least is it possible to copy past that url to access the same website again? I do catch the `$_GET('site)` to generate the right content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep this code in `/students/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /StudentsHelp/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?site=(question)&question=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?site=(register) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^question/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?site=question&question=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^(register)/?$ index.php?site=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: It does not work. It gives me still: `http://localhost/StudentsHelp/?site=question&question=2` (Yes changed the rewritebase to StudentsHelp and the .htaccess is inside of that folder)

Comment: Yes this works. Do i see it right that i need to change my links from `<a href=?site=question>...</a>` to the full path? And if i want to rewrite more sites. (Registration) how do i do this correct.. (new to the .htacces)

Comment: Yes right links need to be like: `<a href="/StudentsHelp/question/2">Question 2</a>`

Comment: For new rules I need to clear requirements like what is pretty URL and how it would be routed?

Comment: I'd like to rout the request `site=`= StudentsHelp (to index) and `site=register` => StudentsHelp/register and so on. So if i understand that right there is no $_GET anymore after this. I need to get it out of the url?

Comment: I added code for `/StudentsHelp/?site=register` as well. Similarly you can build more rules.

Comment: I need to leave for a meeting, will be back in an hour to check comments here.

Comment: Thanks alot!! One last thing. If i add a link to `<a href="StudentsHelp/register">Registrieren</a></td>` it does not find the right site and links me to `StudentsHelp/StudentsHelp/register` if i link to `/register` i get back to root `http://localhost/register`.(this will be a pain to bring on a life server i guess). So i still need to call the index with the right "get" parameters or parse the right infromation out of the url to generate the right page. How do i accomplish it after rewriting? Thanks that you take your time!

Comment: @BennX put a `/` at the begin `/StudentsHelp/register` or use the full URL or use the HTML `base` tag.

Comment: already caught that. My bad working with html for ages and still do such misstakes... I guess i need to parse the url to create the right page ...

Comment: @Prix: Thanks for your comment, yes indeed links need to start with `/`